# scrolling horizontally with fixed left div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

I'm looking for a way to scroll horizontally in a div view, with on the left a sidebar that is fixed. So when there is scrolling (horizontal), everything disappears behind this sidebar.
To illustrate:
[image]
I do not know how this can be done precisely. Can this only through CSS or do it in conjunction with Javascript? And if so, how exactly?

Here's [my working fiddle so far]
`ssss`(http://jsfiddle.net/justamir/fp2xgqL5/)

Comment: Fix the link please.

Comment: The link wents to example.com something Give the fiddle link

Comment: Sorry guys I have just updated my fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a table, to make it scrollable you place it within a div with overflow. If you want a fix column, this must be placed outside the overflowed div. You end up with a layout like this:

```css
.scrollable {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.fixed,
.scrollable {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<table class="fixed">
  <tr>
    <th>FIXED</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>val1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>val2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>val3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>val4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="scrollable">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>val1</td>
      <td>val1</td>
      <td>val1</td>
      <td>val1</td>
      <td>val1</td>
      <td>val1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>val2</td>
      <td>val2</td>
      <td>val2</td>
      <td>val2</td>
      <td>val2</td>
      <td>val2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>val3</td>
      <td>val3</td>
      <td>val3</td>
      <td>val3</td>
      <td>val3</td>
      <td>val3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>val4</td>
      <td>val4</td>
      <td>val4</td>
      <td>val4</td>
      <td>val4</td>
      <td>val4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```